# How do I achieve this zig-zag collection view layout?

Tags: swift, user-interface, layout, collectionview

Here's how I want the cells to look like , [image: Here's how I want the cells to look like]

I'm doing indexPath.row % 3 == 0 but that doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the collection view layout, it is about how do you want to display the cell.

I would suggest to do this logic in [`collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview) as follows:

Assuming that your view controller conforms to `UICollectionViewDelegate`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [.purple, .white, .white, .purple][indexPath.item % 4]
}
```

Thanks to @[vacawama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630618/vacawama) for elegant edit (`[.purple, .white, .white, .purple][indexPath.item % 4]`).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm doing the logic in cellForItem and also tried it in willDisplay cell with no luck, indexPath.row % 2 == 0 doesn't work. I want the cells bg color to look like the pic above.

Comment: No it doesn't work. % 2 only checks if it's even, in the pic above, the layout ( colors) are zig zag, for example the 7th cell should be pink but the code doesn't work because it only checks for even or not.

Comment: @RyanCandall yes got, sorry. Lemme think about it just a little bit :)

Comment: `cell.backgroundColor = [.purple, .white, .white, .purple][indexPath.item % 4]`

Comment: @vacawama so elegant :D don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: @vacawama that works perfectly. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @AhmadF, you can use it in your answer.

Comment: @vacawama the great thing is the approach would is typical for any desired pattern. For instance, let's we want to let it as: .purple, .white, .purple, .white, .white, .purple, it would be simply: `[.purple, .white, .purple, .white, .white, .purple][indexPath.item % 6]`. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.backgroundColor = [.purple, .white, .white, .purple][indexPath.item % 4]
```

Thanks to @vacawama